# Webpack module federation remote micro front end dependency is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, webpack, webpack-module-federation

Using webpack 5 and modules federation, I have a host app that consumes a microfrontend both using react. I have an installed dependency in both the mfe and the host app. If I run the mfe by itself and try to use a method from this dependency it works fine, but when I consume the mfe in the host app and try to use it it is undefinded.

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'login') at Object.login (MessageBus.ts:134:1) at handleSignIn (SignInButton.tsx:18:63)`

Here is what I have, the LoginService is what is not defined:

MFE component:

```js
export const SignInButton = () => {
  const handleSignIn = () => {
    LoginService.login("loginRedirect"); // this is the line that has the error
  };

  return (
    <Button className="motif-button-large btn"  onClick={handleSignIn}>
        Login
    </Button>
  );
};
```

MFE modulefederation.config.ts

```
const { dependencies } = require('./package.json');

module.exports = {
  name: 'map_login',
  filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
  remotes: {},
  exposes: {
    './Login': './src/components/Login/Login.tsx',
  },
  shared: {
    ...dependencies,
    '@ey/mfe-ui-core': { // this is the dependency that is undefined
      requiredVersion: dependencies['@ey/mfe-ui-core']
    },
    react: {
      singleton: true,
      requiredVersion: dependencies.react
    },
    'react-dom': {
      singleton: true,
      requiredVersion: dependencies['react-dom']
    }
  }
};
```

In the hostapp I'm using the mfe like so:

```js
const Login = React.lazy(() => import('map_login/Login'));
```

and the modulefederation.config.ts is very similar:

```
const { dependencies } = require('./package.json');

const { env } = process;

module.exports = {
  name: 'mfe-react-ui-hostspa',
  filename: 'remoteEntry.js',
  remotes: {
    map_login: `map_login@${env.REACT_MFE_LOGIN}/remoteEntry.js`
  },
  exposes: {},
  shared: {
    ...dependencies,
    '@ey/mfe-ui-core': {
      singleton: true,
      requiredVersion: dependencies['@ey/mfe-ui-core']
    },
    react: {
      singleton: true,
      requiredVersion: dependencies.react
    },
    'react-dom': {
      singleton: true,
      requiredVersion: dependencies['react-dom']
    }
  }
};
```

The compiled code of the hostapp looks like this:

```
var SignInButton = function SignInButton() {
  var handleSignIn = function handleSignIn() {
    _ey_mfe_ui_core__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.LoginService.login("loginRedirect"); // this is the line were the error occurs.
  };
  return /*#__PURE__*/(0,react_jsx_runtime__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_3__.jsx)(_ey_xd_motif_react__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2__.MotifButton, {
    className: "motif-button-large btn",
    onClick: handleSignIn,
    children: "Login"
  });
};
```

I've tried several different modulefederation configs but none work, as I mentioned the dependency works fine when the MFE is served by itself.